# Where do lactone groups occur in graphene oxides and how are they identified using FTIR measurements?

Tags: titration, carbon-allotropes

Usually, the literature (for example, Serodre et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.21577/0103-5053.20190167)]) shows the occurrence of lactones in graphene oxides through potentiometric titration measurements. In the nanosheets, do these groups occur in defect regions (such as carboxylic acids and carbonyls) or in the basal plane (such as hydroxyls and epoxide groups)? Furthermore, in the FTIR measurements, how can we identify lactones?

#### Reference

1. Serodre, T.; Oliveira, N.; Miquita, D.; Ferreira, M.; Santos, A.; Resende, V.; Furtado, C. Surface Silanization of Graphene Oxide Under Mild Reaction Conditions. *J. Braz. Chem. Soc.* **2019**. DOI: [10.21577/0103-5053.20190167](https://doi.org/10.21577/0103-5053.20190167).